# How to handleSubmit on button click inside MaterialUI stepper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on Register Form using MaterialUI stepper. Each stepper render a component:

```
const steps = ['Basic informations', 'Profile', 'Review your registration']
```

And there's a Register `button` at the end `step`, click on it should handleSubmit the form data.

I tried to make this concept using this code below, but it didn't work. Can you fix it for me please?

```
const steps = ['Basic informations', 'Profile', 'Review your registration']

export default function Register() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0)
  const [stateRegister, setStateRegister] = useState({})
  const [stateProfile, setStateProfile] = useState({})

  function getStepContent(step) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return <BasicForm stateOfRegister={stateOfRegister} />
      case 1:
        return <ProfileForm stateOfProfile={stateOfProfile} />
      case 2:
        return <Review stateRegister={stateRegister} stateProfile={stateProfile} />
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown step')
    }
  }

  const stateOfRegister = (props) => {
    setStateRegister(props)
  }
  const stateOfProfile = (props) => {
    setStateProfile(props)
  }

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep + 1)
  }

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep - 1)
  }

  const handleNavigate = () => {
    navigate('/')
  }

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const user = { ...stateRegister, ...stateProfile, role: 'user', uid: 'azeq' }
    await addUser(user)
  }

  return (
<React.Fragment>
                {getStepContent(activeStep)}
                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                  {activeStep !== 0 && (
                    <>
                      <Button onClick={handleBack} sx={{ mt: 3, ml: 1 }}>
                        Back
                      </Button>
                    </>
                  )}
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleNext()
                      {
                        activeStep === 3 && handleSubmit()     //this is my try
                      }
                    }}
                    sx={{ mt: 3, ml: 1 }}
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Register' : 'Next'}
                  </Button>
                </Box>
              </React.Fragment>
)
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing? Does it run, but behave incorrectly, or does it not run at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the click handler on the button it might behave the way that you would like.

```
const onNextClick = () => {
  if(activeStep === steps.length - 1)
    handleSubmit()
  else
    handleNext()
}

...
     <Button
       variant="contained"
       onClick={onNextClick}
       sx={{ mt: 3, ml: 1 }}
     >
           {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Register' : 'Next'}
     </Button>
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fix my problem and works as expected!